# Is there a way to select only a certain polygon for editing?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing

I have a spatialite data base with 4300 polygons contained within. I wish to be able to edit the polygons but once i have highlighted the Polygon from the attributes table i find it hard to edit the vertices as when i try to select the cross hairs (vertex) unless i am extremely careful i end up selecting another polygon?

Is there a way of selecting the polygon i wish to edit from within the attributes table and making only that polygon editable? I know i could export it, edit it and then merge it back into the Spatialite database but this is additional steps that i would rather avoid if possible.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder would the snapping options help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique identifier, like a id field, you can copy that to the clipboard, close attribute table and editing mode, right-click on layer name `-> Query`, and fill in

`"< fieldname>" = '< insert clipboard here>'`

Keep an eye on single and double quotes. The query will return you the single item for editing.

Disadvantage is that you might get spaces between formerly fitting neighbouring objects.

Comment: Hi Andre, worked a charm thank you so much has saved me hours of head aches !!!